# Unserialize(): Error at offset 3348 of 14577 bytes

Tags: opencart

I have error in opencart

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 3348 of 14577 bytes in ..\project\library\DbSettingsHelper.php on line 154

can anyone tell what is the reason?

Comment: What did you do before this happened,did you edit anything?

Comment: i have just backup of my database